# @import "@" causing vue project to break

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

I have a 2 child components i'm trying to add to a login form (login through email and phone)

when running npm run serve I get a “Cannot read property 'components' of undefined”.
After changing my

```
@import "@/assets/neighscss/scss/_variables";
```

to

```
@import "../../../assets/neighscss/scss/_variables";
```

on the child components, it works without problems. I wanted to know what the root cause may be and if referencing like this will effect my app when I deploy it to a live server

Comment: Is your alias configuration (@) pointing to the parent directory of assets?

Comment: by the way, the name of the file is "variables" and "_variables"

Comment: it's _variables, just typed it in wrong here, sorry, edited @JavierMolinasVilas

Comment: @PatricNox How do I check that? I'm using webstorm. Is that where you go to settings/directories and set src as resource root? if so, yes I have. It's weird coz when i use regular import it recognizes "@" but when using "@import" it redlines

Comment: tsconfig if typescript, otherwise `configureWebpack` object (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions)